# sentence into tokens using php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert a sentence into array of words.
I want to convert them into a stream of tokens and assign a variable name to each token.

Given string `I am a girl`

and expected output

- Token[0] = I
- Token[1] = am
- Token[2] = a
- Token[3] = girl

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) for this,

Code:

```
$token = explode(" ","I am a girl");
var_dump($token);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "I"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "am"
  [2] =>
  string(1) "a"
  [3] =>
  string(4) "girl"
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer. But I am getting NULL as an answer

Comment: Got the answer. You have used the variable name as "token" but in the below line you are using the variable name as "tokens".

Comment: Can you please tell how can I store these tokens as variables and call them by their index values. Thanks

Comment: you can use, 0,1,2.... to access index of the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
$token = explode(" ","I am a girl.");
print_r($token);
```

***Explode*** is using to convert a string into array

Comment: To convert a string into array

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: thanks.Its working. Actually I want to first save the tokens in an array and then use each token for further analysis. So how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

`explode()` is split a string by string to array.
like

```
$string = 'a, b, c, d';
print_r(explode(',', $string));
```

output:

```
array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

so you can try it.

```
explode(' ', 'I am a girl')
```

Comment: Thankyou. Its working. But how can I call each token by its index value and save it in a variable?

Comment: you can use `foreach`. `foreach($array as $value){   // your code    }`.